# Updating MiniProfiler.MVC3 NuGet package after editing MiniProfiler.cs in App_Start

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, nuget, mvc-mini-profiler, nuget-package

In the [MiniProfiler.MVC3](http://nuget.org/packages/MiniProfiler.MVC3) NuGet package, it creates a file in App_Start that is used to control MiniProfiler settings (the SqlFormatter to use, modifications to the ViewEngines, when to start MiniProfiler, etc.).

There are a lot of TODO comments in this file talking about how to change the code to perform how you want.  This is great, but when the NuGet package is updated, it will see that I've changed the file and not pull down the updated version.  The problem here is that I lose any updates to that file, and depending on what else updated in the package, making it unusable (for example, when upgrading MiniProfiler.MVC3 from version 1.9 to version 2.0.1 after modifying MiniProfiler.cs in App_Start, the project will no longer build because of needed changes to that file in the 2.0.1 version).

What is the best way to handle this?  Should I create my own file in App_Start and not modify the one in the NuGet package, ensuring that I will always get the full update when upgrading to the latest version of the NuGet package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could backup the file in App_Start, update it, then merge the files manually, or using a merge tool.  You'd probably end up doing this anyways if you're using source control.

Answer (score 0):

Quick-and-dirty: create the file you want.  Then copy over/merge every time you upgrade with nugget.  Or with every compile.  The added build time is negligible.

Slightly better: use the precompile event in visual studio and compare the files.  If they differ - either copy over or tell the user.  I can't figure out a way to show a message box, or similar, on the top of my head but one could always create a new file with a compilation error and some text nearby "discrepancy in the xxx file".

Answer (score 0):

try using mercurial queues.  You can get your code to the point you want (excluding the file you refer to), and then commit.  Make changes to your file, and push it to a queue.  Make sure to exclude it from any future updates (manually), and then when you want to update your package, pop it off your code base.  This will make it look like it used to, and run the nuget update.  Then you can push the queue back to the code, and your changes will re-applied.  It might take a bit of fiddling, but worth a look.

For reference:

- https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/MqExtension
- https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/MqTutorial
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Mercurial_Queues